# Run gparted from ubuntu 14.04 live

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gparted, live-cd

I can not find a way to start `gparted` from ubuntu 14.04 Live CD.

There is an icon on desktop for "Ubuntu Software Center", if I open it - it states that gparted is installed, but there is no icon to launch gparted on desktop. Also there is no menu with installed programs.
Also there is no icon to start terminal.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - I am able lo switch to text console, but when I write `gparted` there - it throws error "`Can not open display`"

Comment: This does not really look suitable for [sf]. Should be migrated to [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just press the command button on your keyboard (aka windows key) and type  **gparted** to find the program.

to open a terminal in ubuntu press **strg + alt + t**. gparted can be run from there using

```
$ sudo gparted.
```